# Animating only when in viewport

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I'm trying to adapt the following technique:

`https://codepen.io/donovanh/pen/rmzNZJ`

To a studying project, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I uploaded parts of my own project here:

`https://codepen.io/cucurutcho/pen/KKWRrov`

Basically, the JS is working to add custom classes to elements when they are visible on screen and therefore do some animation to it. But on my example, the classes are not being added and I'm not sure why, I'm probably missing something super simple here, but anyone that could shed some light is much appreciated! To make it easier, on my codepen (the second one) you can see the elements that have the class "show-on-scroll" don't work the way they do on the first codepen, where I got the technique from. This is the JS code that should do it:

```
    // Detect request animation frame
var scroll = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
             // IE Fallback
             function(callback){ window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60)};
var elementsToShow = document.querySelectorAll('.show-on-scroll'); 

function loop() {

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(elementsToShow, function(element){
      if (isElementInViewport(element)) {
        element.classList.add('is-visible');
      } else {
        element.classList.remove('is-visible');
      }
    });

    scroll(loop);
}

// Call the loop for the first time
loop();

// Helper function from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7557433/274826
function isElementInViewport(el) {
  // special bonus for those using jQuery
  if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
    el = el[0];
  }
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    (rect.top <= 0
      && rect.bottom >= 0)
    ||
    (rect.bottom >= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight))
    ||
    (rect.top >= 0 &&
      rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight))
  );
}
```

Comment: You may find it more straightforward to use IntersectionObserver on each of the elements you want to animate - it will tell you when the element is in view so you can add the animation and tell you when it is out of view so you can remove it. You can choose the proportion that is in view for the observation to be triggered.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @AHaworth, will defo look into it!